# Swift How to add key value in NSMutable array

Tags: swift, replace, nsmutablearray

I have one nsmutable Array , How to add one keyvalue in nsmutable array  at index number

This is array

```
 (
           {
           id = 1;
           name = "Tommy";
       },
           {
           id = 2;
           name = "Dad";
       },
           {
           id = 3;
           name = "Mom";
       },
           {
           id = 4;
           name = "Vic";
       },
           {
           id = 5;
           name = "Tom";
       },
           {
           id = 6;
           name = "Pam";
       }
   )
```

Now Index number 3 how to add "Class = 4th" and change name

```
 {
               id = 4;
               name = "Nishant ";
               class = "4th"
           }
```

Please give ME solution 
i am new in Swift.

Comment: Show what you tried, what result you're looking for and what you got

Comment: in id number 4 i have change name value and add class key Please Help me